# Infinite power series with unique factorization possible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, power-series, unique-factorization-domains

> Q: Is it possible to define a space of power series over $\mathbb{Q}$ with unique factorization?

It is known that this is possible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

[converging power series over $p$-adic integers is a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346060/converging-power-series-over-p-adic-integers-is-a-ufd?rq=1)

Comment: How is that factorization any issue for being a UFD? We don't care about units in our factorizations.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft you are right, thanks.

Comment: Given any field $F$, not only does $F[[x]]$ have unique factorization, it moreover is a principal ideal domain.

Answer (score 1):

For any field $K$, the ring of power series $R_m=K[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$ is a UFD. We can prove this by induction:

[Prove that the ring of formal power series over a field is an UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374159/prove-that-the-ring-of-formal-power-series-over-a-field-is-an-ufd)